# Should I follow up after interview? They didn't call when they said they would

Tags: interviewing

I recently interviewed at an agency for a web development internship. It went pretty well, and the interviewer said they'd call me the day after (latest by the afternoon). They said that TWICE during the interview and when I was leaving as well. But it's been two days and still, no call. Should I email and follow up? If so, what should I write in the email? It's frustrating when they make a false commitment like this to call on a specific day and not follow through. They could've at least given me some BS line like "we'll call you if we're interested" then I would've pretty much known that I didn't get it rather than having this false hope.

Comment: Can we please remove the "duplicate" mark? This is NOT a duplicate as it specifically asks about what do if they the employer told you they would call back by a specific date and time. This is a different question to asking if you should checkup without being told you would get a definite response. I was looking for this question but skipped straight past to the "duplicates" erroneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone tells you that they will call by a certain time, that gives you a reason to follow-up without appearing as though you are pestering them. Typically I use the "I was told..." followed by "...and I haven't heard" as part of my introduction and I've never gotten a negative vibe from anyone I've called like that.

Basically, you're putting them on the defensive and prompting them to respond one way or another without actually making anyone **feel** defensive. Additionally, it shows your interest in the position.  It's the best of both worlds.

I personally think it gets back to the Golden Rule. You want people to follow up with you, so you diligently follow up with them when it's necessary.

Comment: Thank you Christopher. I have e-mailed them with a brief, polite follow-up message inquiring whether they were still interested in hiring me. Hopefully things go well and they answer in the affirmative. Actually, between the time I asked the question and now, I just got an email from another company inviting me for an interview (feels good haha)! Either way, I'm not giving up! Thanks!